# Rectangular grass lawn with flower beds on its edges problem

Tags: geometry, polynomials

> A rectangular grass lawn is $3x^2y$ meters long and  $4xy$ meters wide. On its edges are flower beds which are $x$ meters wide. What is the area planted by grass only?

```
From: 2018 Metrobank-MTAP-DepEd Math Challenge Elimination Round Grade 7 Question 28
```

The answer is  $12x^3y^2 - 8x^2y - 6x^3y + 4x^2$ square meters but I don't know how it arrived to that answer.

All I know is $12x^3y^2$ came from the area of the rectangular grass lawn which is $(3x^2y)(4xy)$ and $4x^2$  came from the area of the flower beds which is $x^2$ times four since there are four edges in a rectangle.

Can someone explain where did $-8x^2y$ and $-6x^3y$ came from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a drawing of the lawn

[image]

The gray area is the grass and the red and green areas are the flower bed edges.

As Mattew Daly pointed out in his solution, the size of the gray area could be given by
$$(4xy - 2x) \times (3x^2y-2x)$$
Which give the answer directly.

An other approach is by inclusion-exclusion principle. We start with the total area of the lawn
$$(4xy)\times(3x^2y) = 12x^2y^2$$
We then remove the green patchs
$$\text{Area of Green Patch} = (4xy)\times x = 4x^2y$$
$$12x^2y^2 - 2\times 4x^2y \qquad\text{since there are 2 green patches}$$
We then remove the red patchs
$$\text{Area of Red Patch} = (3x^2y)\times x = 3x^3y$$
$$12x^2y^2 - 2\times 4x^2y - 2\times 3x^3y\qquad\text{since there are 2 red patches}$$
Now the corner have been removed twice, we need to add then to the result
$$\text{Area of corner} = x\times x = x^2$$
$$12x^2y^2 - 2\times 4x^2y - 2\times 3x^3y + 4\times x^2\qquad\text{since there are 4 corners}$$
Which gives you the answer
$$12x^2y^2 - 8x^2y - 6x^3y + 4x^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the beds are on the grass lawn.  So the length of the lawn is that is grass only is $3x^2y-2x$ and the width is $4xy-2x$ (since the length and width are both shortened by $x$ on each of their sides).  Multiply those binomials together and the product is the answer they gave.